# Настройка субдомена в bind9

Tags: dns, bind9

Есть следующая конфигурация зоны :

```
$ttl 38400
xn--90acbu5aj5f.xn--p1ai.   IN  SOA xn--90acbu5aj5f.xn--p1ai. edwedw.gmail.com. (
            1490115240
            10800
            3600
            604800
            38400 )
xn--90acbu5aj5f.xn--p1ai.   IN  A   188.93.210.159
xn--90acbu5aj5f.xn--p1ai.   IN  NS  xn--90acbu5aj5f.xn--p1ai.
demo.xn--90acbu5aj5f.xn--p1ai.  IN  NS  xn--90acbu5aj5f.xn--p1ai.
www.xn--90acbu5aj5f.xn--p1ai.   IN  CNAME   xn--90acbu5aj5f.xn--p1ai.
188.93.210.159.xn--90acbu5aj5f.xn--p1ai.    IN  PTR xn--90acbu5aj5f.xn--p1ai
```

Вроде должно откликаться на dig @188.93.210.159 demo.xn--90acbu5aj5f.xn--p1ai., однако выводит:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P4-Ubuntu <<>> @188.93.210.159 demo.xn--90acbu5aj5f.xn--p1ai.
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id: 5004
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;demo.xn--90acbu5aj5f.xn--p1ai. IN  A

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 188.93.210.159#53(188.93.210.159)
;; WHEN: Wed Mar 22 09:57:28 UTC 2017
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 58
```

Comment: Вы dig по умолчанию запрашиваете "A" запись, но у вас в домене нет "A" записи для demo

Comment: А если вы хотите полноценный субдомен и пожтому написали в основной зоне NS для demo у вас должена быть в конфиге отдельная зона demo со своей SOA и т.п.

Comment: Попробовал добавить demo.xn--90acbu5aj5f.xn--p1ai IN  A   188.93.210.159 - апач не распознает разницу между demo b е demo, попробовал создать отдельную зону master demo.xn--90acbu5aj5f.xn--p1ai  - тож самое. Чтото не то делаю

Comment: стоп. не путайте апач и dns. задача dns отдать ip. если по `dig demo... ` вы получаете нормальный ответ и `ping demo...` пытается пинговать нужный вам ip - значит dns настроен верно. Если по данному имени открывается не та страница, которая ожидалась - это уже настройка виртуальных доменов в конфиге апача

Comment: Да, проблема была в настройках Апача. В bind9 указал две зоны

Comment: Ну ради одной A записи для субдомена делать отдельную зону не обязательно. собственно эту A пишите и все. NS для нее не делаете

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение:

- в bind добавить обе зоны
- верно настроить апач (у меня не был прописан ServerName)